# Can I say I will be there 2.00pm at the latest? Or for the latest

Tags: prepositions

Is it grammatically correct to say "2.00 pm at the latest" or "2.00 pm for the latest"?

Answer (score 2):

The correct expression is *at the latest*.

> I will be there at 2:00 pm at the latest.

This means that the latest time I will be there is 2:00 pm.

But you could say

> I will be there at 2:00 pm for the latest.

But here *latest* is an adjective that acts as a noun and it would be understood that you are talking about *the latest **something***, as in *news*, *development*, *update*, *report*, etc:

> I will be there at 2:00 pm for the latest news/development/etc.

Comment: Is it right? > I will do it by latest today.